# Docusign Users API not properly filtering users by email?

Tags: docusignapi

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/list/

I'm using user impersonation to send envelopes via DocuSign Python API, but need to find the user_id of the user to impersonate.

Running this successfully returns a list of users

```
client = ApiClient()
client.set_base_path(...)
client.set_default_header(...)
users_api = UsersApi(client)
users_api.list(client.account_id)
```

However if I try to filter by emails found in the command above with `users_api.list(client.account_id, email="test@company.com")`

It returns bad request: 400 Bad Request: No User was found for given criteria

Is this a bug on the DocuSign side or is there an issue with our code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have a user test@company.com? the API tells you they can't find a user with this email.

You can also use the **email_substring** to filter with parts of the email address (Say just a first name) to filter this way.

The API returns 400 in this case to tell you no users were found, not that you made a bad API call.

Comment: Yes, test@company.com was just an example. If I filter by email in the account returned in the original users_api.list(client.account_id), it returns 400 users not found.

Comment: did you try the email_substring option?

Comment: Yup, I tried it as well and it did not work. It returned the same error. Tried this with 10 emails / substrings of emails for users that exist.